# Android add textview above other textviews

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I developed an app that dynamically creates textviews, and the desired result would be:

```
textview1
textview2
textview3
```

(then when the user creates a new textview)

```
textview4
textview1
textview2
textview3
```

but as of now, textview4 goes under textview3

the textviews are under a linearlayout.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show some code with the xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
addView (View child, int index)
```

Index being the position in the view (0 if you want to have it at the top)